# How to use jwt authentication for static served content?

Tags: html, node.js, authentication, jwt

I have a site composed by a **frontend** (written in Vue) and a **backend** (written in node).
The **api** use the **jwt** authentication, so that only a logged in user can make requests to the backend.

The jwt is placed in the `Authorization: Bearer xxx`.

The problem comes when I have **sensitive images or documents statically served** such as identity cards.

Let's say I have a **sensitive image** statically served. Now, I could just add the **jwt authentication** also for that statically served image, no problem, but in the **frontend side**, how do I tell to the browser to **put my jwt on the request**?

```html
<img href="/my/sensitive/image.png" />
```

Note that the jwt is not known a priori, it is retreived by the user login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cookies. Store the JSON Web Token in a cookie (preferably with HTTPOnly, Secure and SameSite flags on), so that the browser automatically appends the value on every request to your origin.

This is a good idea from the security point of view, too - if client-side JS cannot access the token at any time, the risk of leaking it via a cross-site scripting vulnerability drops to zero.

Comment: Sounds good! I am using passport on nodejs (if you know it) and it is almost built in using a cookie session on top of the jwt (I think it would be also more performant).

Comment: I wait some days to see other answers and then I mark this as the chosen one, thank you!

Comment: By all means, use whatever the framework provides out of the box - it's probably the safest option. Also, hint: you can always change the approved answer later, no need to hold back :)